# Java Spring - passwordEncoder how to generate a random password

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am working on the "forgot" password section for this application - and I am curious if the passwordEncoder function can generate a random password to give for the user. Or is there a different dependency to use?

Is there anything like

```
String randomPass = passwordEncoder.generateRand()
```

I was wondering if there was a more lib based solution - than something bespoke?

Comment: Whenever I'm curious about something, I research the subject to find out.

Comment: `PasswordEncoder` has only two methods - `encode()` and `matches()`. You can see that from its documentation.

Comment: @Kayaman yes - I was wondering if there was a more lib based solution - than something bespoke - didn't want to reinvent the wheel so to speak

Comment: @slim - yes that's why I proposed the question here to see if there is another lib package that would usually support this requirement - than relying on something bespoke

Comment: This is stupid - its not off topic to ask for the best way to solve what should be a common problem -- if you are unfamiliar with a framework/possible lib system

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
public static String alphaNumericString(int len) {
    String AB = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    Random rnd = new Random();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(len);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        sb.append(AB.charAt(rnd.nextInt(AB.length())));
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Then:

```
String randomPass = passwordEncoder.encode(alphaNumericString(10))
```

Comment: _ well that's a very manual way though - I was wondering if there was something more lib provided via the Password Encoding package